# How to get the limit of the equation?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I have got the equation as follow,

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}\left(1+ \dfrac{\mathit{r_j} \cdot {u_j}}{{|{v_j}|^{1/\beta}}}\right)$

where $r\sim N(0, 1)$, $v\sim N(0, 1)$, and $u\sim N(0, 0.6^2)$. $\beta$ equals to $\frac{3}{2}$. My question is how to find the limit of the above equation? Anyone can give some suggestions?